# Compile in Linux/Unix issue C++

Tags: c++, linux, unix

This is only part of an overall program and compiles and runs fine in Windows, however it does not like my strcpy in Linux/Unix. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Also a note, I am not allowed to use string, only cstring.

Song.cpp

```
#include "Song.h"


Song::Song()
{
}


Song::~Song()
{
}


Song::Song(char* title, char* artist, char* duration, char* album)
{
strcpy(this->title,50,title);
strcpy(this->artist, 50, artist);
strcpy(this->duration, 50, duration);
strcpy(this->album, 50, album);
}

void Song::setTitle(char* title)
{
this->title= title;
}
void Song::setArtist(char* artist)
{
this->artist = artist;
}
void Song::setDuration(char* duration)
{
this->duration= duration;
}
void Song::setAlbum(char* album)
{
this->album= album;
}

char* Song::getTitle()
{
return this->title;
}
char* Song::getArtist()
{
return this->artist;
}
char* Song::getDuration()
{
return this->duration;
}
char* Song::getAlbum()
{
return this->album;
}
```

Song.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

class Song
{
private:
    char* title;
    char* artist;
    char* duration;
    char* album;

public:
    Song();
    ~Song();

    Song(char* title, char* artist, char* duration, char* album);

    void setTitle(char* title);
    void setArtist(char* artist);
    void setDuration(char* duration);
    void setAlbum(char* album);

    char* getTitle();
    char* getArtist();
    char* getDuration();
    char* getAlbum();


};
```

Comment: Check Strcpy api, length can't be specified. Strncp can, and size is the third param

Comment: Thank you, the Strncpy worked. I tried that before, but never moved the size to the third parameter.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?"  IMO, using `strcpy` is a mistake in C++ programs.  Use `std::string` and all these sorts of low-level C oriented raw pointer to char issues, just disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't allocated any memory for `strcpy` to copy into. Thus your constructor invokes undefined behavior.

You need to allocate a character array first. But then you also need to deallocate it in each of your setters. Otherwise the memory will be leaked, since you're reassigning the pointer that manages it.